# React JS OpenWeatherMap API Key not working in the .env but working directly in app.js

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, openweathermap

I am trying to put the OpenWeatherMap API Key in the `.env` file but when I call it, it console log a 401 error (Unauthorized), and when I do call it without the `.env` file directly in the `app.js` file it works perfectly.

App.js:

```
const [currentWeather, setCurrentWeather] = useState(null);
  const [forecast, setForecast] = useState(null);

  const handleOnSearchChange = (searchData) => {
    const [lat, lon] = searchData.value.split(" ");

    const currentWeatherFetch = fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY}`
    );

    const forecastFetch = fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY}`
    );

    Promise.all([currentWeatherFetch, forecastFetch])
      .then(async (response) => {
        const weatherResponse = await response[0].json();
        const forecastResponse = await response[1].json();

        setCurrentWeather({ city: searchData.label, ...weatherResponse });
        setForecast({ city: searchData.label, ...forecastResponse });
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  };

  console.log(currentWeather);
  console.log(forecast);
```

.env:

```
REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY = "199023c4fb4dc2be4f6ae2b9d23f12bd";
```

Answer (score 0):

What engine are you using in your app. Different engines import environment variables differently. I believe for instance with vite you must prepend your variables with the VITE_ keyword. I would also see if it's even picking up your variables at all. Add this to the top of your handleOnSearchChange function.

```
console.info("SECRET KEY", process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY);
```

EDIT:
I think your problem is in your definition of your env variable. Remove the quotes and see if it works.

```
REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY=12345 // remove the quotes and spacing
```

Now I no longer get the {"cod":401, "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}

Comment: what do you mean by engine, please? i'm using ```npx create-react-app``` and it console log me this SECRET KEY "199023c4fb4dc2be4f6ae2b9d23f12bd";

Comment: Alright so you're using create-react-app and not vite or something else. Depending on what is you're using to run your app the way the env is loaded might differ but that does not seem to be the case here

Comment: If you have edited your env while the app is still running you might have to shut down the local dev server and start it up again "npm (or yarn) run start". https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: I restarted my server a lot of times but still not working, I'm really confused.

Comment: Where you able to confirm whether or not you're env variables are even being picked up or not? @YacineAyechi

Comment: yes, they are being picked up

Comment: @YacineAyechi I would delete your comment containing your secret key. I was able to use it to verify that your endpoint actually works. The only thing that I notice is that if for some reason your latitude or longitude is missing I get a {"cod":"400","message":"Nothing to geocode"}. I went a step further and implemented your code in one of my projects and it works just fine.